# Use an NSURLProtectionSpace or SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates() for HTTPS server validation?

Tags: ios

I want to confirm the identity of the server my client is communicating with over a HTTPS connection.

There would appear to be two options, however I've not been able to find anything describing what the advantages/disadvantages of one method over the over is. Which of these is more secure and why?

1) Create a self-signed certificate which is used by the server and added to the application bundle and set as an anchor certificate using SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates()

2) Create an NSURLProtectionSpace and set its realm, host, port, and protocol, then compare it with the NSURLProtectionSpace in the NSURLAuthenticationChallenge passed into willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:.

Does it make much difference which of these authentication mechanisms is used to verify the server?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Technical Note 2232: HTTPS Server Trust Evaluation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html) describes best practices for evaluating trust over SSL/TLS.

It's not clear from the question wether you're interested in only self signed certificates or evaluating trust in general. In general, avoid using self signed certificates in production environments. If you must use a self signed server certificate, you should be rigorous in verifying that the credentials are what you expect. At the very least you should check the public key the server provides against a known value (SSL public key pinning). An example to get you started is [here](https://github.com/quellish/PublicKeyPinningExample).